# Ajax Form Submission not working in Wordpress Plugin (400 Bad Response)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been at this for hours and I can't seem to figure it out:
I have a form that inserts a database row and I'm doing a jQuery.ajax call through admin-ajax.php

Whatever I try I keep getting "**400 Bad Response"**.

Things I AM doing:

1. Passing the ajax url via wp_localize_script. This seems to be
   working correctly
2. Adding the action hooks wp_ajax and wp_ajax_nopriv
3. Serializing my form. Running a query that I previously tested in a
       NON-ajax setup (working)

This is **class-pluginname-public.php**

```
function __construct() {

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_public_resources'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_public_resources'));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_name', array($this, 'my_action_name') );    // If called from admin panel
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_name', array($this, 'my_action_name') ); 
        add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'rws_popUpInit'));

    }

    function my_action_name(){
        global $wpdb;

        $tableprefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $table_name = $tableprefix.'wpr_roulettewheel';
        $data = array( 
                'first_name' => $_POST['first-name'], 
                'last_name' => $_POST['last-name'],
                'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
                'phone_number' => $_POST['phone-number'],

            );
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data);
        wp_die();
    }
```

**wheelspin.js**

```
jQuery("#rws_mainpopupform").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: popupdisplaysettings.ajaxurl,
        action: "my_action_name",
        data: jQuery("#rws_mainpopupform").serialize(),
        error:   function(response) {
              console.log(response);  
            }
    });
return false;

});
```

**HTML:**

```
function rws_popUpInit(){
echo'
    <form id="rws_mainpopupform" class="ui large form" method="post" action="">
```

**enqueue_public_resources(){**

```
$datatoBePassed = array(

            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wheelpopup', 'popupdisplaysettings', $datatoBePassed );
```

Comment: What is you actual table name. It looks like you are adding the prefix twice?

Comment: it's 'wa_wpr_roulettewheel". I tested that query with a non-ajax approach and it was working. Anyway, I can just replace the entire my_action_name() function contents with console.log('test'); and I'm still getting 400 Bad Response

Comment: I also tried replacing the data with some random data (not my form), same problem. I can't seem to get even the most basic working example up

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was all because I was incorrectly using the 
'wp_ajax' and 'wp_ajax_nopriv' hooks in the public class of the website.

Even if your code runs / is meant to run in the public class, these hooks need to be called in the admin class. Super counter-intuitive.

from the Wordpress Codex:
Note 2: Both front-end and back-end Ajax requests use admin-ajax.php so is_admin() will always return true in your action handling code. **When selectively loading your Ajax script handlers for the front-end and back-end**, and using the is_admin() function, your **wp_ajax_(action) and wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) hooks MUST be inside the is_admin() === true** part.

So either put the hooks inside the is_admin part or use DOING_AJAX or something like that